# What is karma vipakam in hinduism.

Tags: scripture, karma

I heard that there is book by this name. It states the karmas and the results of them.

Comment: Here is the link of the book (Sanskrit-Hindi) : https://archive.org/details/KarmaVipakaSamhitaTikaBhashyaVastiRamVenkateswaraSteamPress. But do u simply want a link of the book or something more?

Comment: It would be great if it is in english or telugu.and btw is karma vipakam from buddhism different from hinduism?

Comment: I think it is available in Telugu. You can search on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let's see what is  meaning of the word Karma-Vipaka in general. The term consist of two words **Karma (action) + Vipaka ( The result. Fruition of those  Karma).** There is also a book called Karma-Vipak Samhita also called Prayascitta Sudhanidhi ,written by great scholar  [**Sayanacharya**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KnPoYxrRfc0C&pg=PA3885&lpg=PA3885&dq=karma%20vipaka%20samhita%20shodhganga&source=bl&ots=Y8JyE7jDB2&sig=Fg-sF6tE6UmHX8zP2MP1IaKclF8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj76prHzcHcAhUMso8KHcHwA4oQ6AEwBXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) - content of which Lord Shiva himself described to Devi Parvati for welfare of all the world . So this book is basically a dialogue between Shiva and Parvati about Actions of human beings and  outcomes of those actions i.e. Karmas.

---

Karma Vipak Samhita is mainly discussing about Past life and past karmas of human beings like on which constlation (Nakshatra) he was born and what karmas he has done in his past life. The text also talks about the atonement of past life acuumulated sins and Karmas.

I am here jotting down the chapterwise subjects  described in the text.

**Chapter 1 -**

1. Introduction to the Nakshatras.
2. Definations related to Nakshatras.
3. Identification of Zodiac sign from Nakshatras.
4. Karma.
5. clover or enjoyments.
6. atonement

**Chapter 2 -**

1. Three types of karmas (actions) of Human beings. - Prarabdha , Sanchit , Kriyamaan.
2. Four type of sons according to past life karmas.
3. atonement
4. Names of type of anatonement.
5. Description of Hells.
6. Five great sins or Maha-Patakas.
7. Small sins or Upa-Patakas.
8. Special anatonement of special type of sins - Brahma hatya , Drinking wine , gold robbary etc.

**Chapter 3-6** are talking about Nakshatras.

---

Here is [**Karma-Vipaka Samhita**](https://archive.org/details/KarmaVipakaSamhitaTikaBhashyaVastiRamVenkateswaraSteamPress) in Sanskrit-Slokas and Hindi Tika (commentary) - 
 And 
And here is a  Hindi research article describing the content of the text in very detail [**ShodhGanga**](http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/78407)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If it is possible can u provide book in english online or for purchase.

Comment: @Visheshreddy - Unfortunately I haven't yet found the text with english translation , and probably it's not there. But if found I will surely inform you about that. Currently I  myself am translating the Hindi text in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will also try, if found then i will put it here.